# Изменение параметров Button Zoom-In

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, zoom

Всем привет.

У меня на странице реализован panzoom, подгружаемый из этой библиотеки: [jquery.panzoom.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/3.2.2/jquery.panzoom.js)

Ещё  библиотеки в коде:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mousewheel/1.0.5/mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

```js
<script>
  
    (function() {
        var $section = $('div').first();
        $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
            $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
            $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
            $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
            $reset: $section.find(".reset")
        });
    
        var instance = panzoom(element, {
            maxZoom: 7,
            minZoom: 0.3
        });
    })();
    
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.page-header{
}
div#page {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
#options{
    margin: 1em 1em 0em 1em;
}
#myCarousel img{
    width:100%;
}
.optionBox,#optionHead1,#optionHead2{
    text-align:center;
}
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: #202020;
}
.buttons{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}
.state-icon {
    left: -5px;
}
.list-group-item-primary {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="buttons">
                        <button type="button" class =" zoom-out btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class =" zoom-in btn btn-default">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="reset btn btn-primary">Исходный размер</button>
                </div>
                <div id="imgDiv">
                    <div class="item active panzoom">
                        <img src="https://iili.io/HQL4kLg.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Dicom">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

В скрипте есть maxScale, установленный на 6. Но мне его не хватает. Пытался изменить через:

```js
var $(instance) = panzoom(element,
     { maxScale: 7,
});
```

Но не сработало.
Как его увеличить?

Comment: Вы уверены? В коде я вижу только minScale: 0.3, maxScale: 6,  а maxZoom там и в помине нет.

Comment: Простите, ошибка. Поправлю в вопросе.
Да, там действительно min и maxScale. Но сути вопроса это вроде не меняет?

Comment: Не видно области самого изображения. Предоставленный код не полный. Нужен полный код. Гадать здесь никто не любит, не понимая всей данности.

Comment: Простите. Новенький здесь. Я обновил вопрос, добавил полный код

Comment: снизу дополнил ответ, посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке которую вы используете нет параметра `maxZoom` скорее всего поэтому и не обрабатывается: `maxZoom: 7`. Используйте параметр `maxScale`

Вот если использовать офф библиотеку расшаренную на github:
https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom

```
https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js
```

То данная библиотека как раз таки принимает значения:

```
var instance = panzoom(element, {
  maxZoom: 1,
  minZoom: 0.1
});
```

**UPD:**
**В вашем коде jquery много путаницы. Я предложу ответ на чистом js**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    const elem = document.querySelector('.panzoom');
    minBtn = document.querySelector('.zoom-out');
    maxBtn = document.querySelector('.zoom-in');
    resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
    
    const panzoom = Panzoom(elem, {
        maxScale: 14,
        minScale: 0.1
      })

    minBtn.addEventListener("click", panzoom.zoomOut);    
    maxBtn.addEventListener("click", panzoom.zoomIn);    
    resetBtn.addEventListener("click", panzoom.reset);

});
```

```css
.page-header{
}
div#page {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
#options{
    margin: 1em 1em 0em 1em;
}
#myCarousel img{
    width:100%;
}
.optionBox,#optionHead1,#optionHead2{
    text-align:center;
}
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: #202020;
}
.buttons{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}
.state-icon {
    left: -5px;
}
.list-group-item-primary {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/4.0.0/panzoom.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-mousewheel/1.0.5/mousewheel.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class =" zoom-out btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class =" zoom-in btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="reset btn btn-primary">Исходный размер</button>
            </div>
            <div id="imgDiv">
                <div class="item active panzoom">
                    <img src="https://iili.io/HQL4kLg.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Dicom">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

У меня он прекрасно работает.